# How can I deploy an asp.net web application on my local iis?

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, publish

[image]I am trying to publish a web application I made on my local iis, but when I try to run it I get all sorts of errors, mostly with the aspx files that cannot inherit from the original files they inherit from and they also cannot access the functions  from the code behind files that I have. The code behind files are not there after I deploy the project and I am curious as to how I can access them. I do not know how I should deploy an asp.net web application on my local server so any help would be greatly appreciated as I am very lost.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Visual Studio?

Comment: Visual Studio is what I am using

Answer (score 0):

how are you publishing your website?
I am guessing not through web deploy - hence the missing files

by th exception screen shot you provided, it seems like you are missing files, specificaly there is no `Site.Master` found (which your page use as master page)

to use visual studio publish tool, on the visual studio, right click your web application and chose `publish`, on the publish method, chose `web deploy`

fill in your service url (`localhost` for local iis) then the site name you have created on your iis

a screen shot of how it may look from the doc link mention below

[image: [](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis/_static/image14.png)]

> side note - depend on your visual studio version, ui of publish tool may be different, but option name are pretty much the same

more info checkout this microsoft doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

Comment: Thank you so much. That was exactly the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @P.Griffin glad to hear you got it sorted.  For future googler reference, please mark as answer if it did answer your question